Unable to boot to Windows, says boot disk is unavailable after installing Ubuntu
I have two drives, both 500 GB NVMe. One is the Windows drive, which I partitioned to install Ubuntu. I followed this video to do so. I am giving what information I feel is important, please ask me to add more information.
Linux boots OK, but my computer is unable to boot Windows. There is no specific error code at a blue screen, just a simple message that Windows boot drive is not accessible. In the attached image is what I am able to see from Windows.

I have also run the Boot-Repair tool on Ubuntu. Do I share it here (yes)?
I was suggested to post this question here from Ask Ubuntu.
EDIT: Adding the Ubuntu boot-repair output.
    boot-repair-4ppa2081                                              [20241119_1702]

============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => Windows is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.
 => Windows is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme1n1.

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi /efi/Boot/fbx64.efi 
                       /efi/Boot/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/cbmr_driver.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/SecureBootRecovery.efi 
                       /efi/OEM/Boot/bootmgfw.efi /efi/OEM/Boot/bootmgr.efi

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p3: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p4: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 10 or 11
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

nvme0n1p5: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p6: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

nvme0n1p7: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

nvme1n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme1n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1 (linux):   The OS now in use - Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS on nvme0n1p7
OS#2 (windows):   Windows 10 or 11 on nvme0n1p4

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: GA106M [GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q] Alder Lake-P GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] from NVIDIA Corporation Intel Corporation
BOOT_IMAGE of the installed session in use:
/boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-41-generic root=UUID=539492ba-b8c5-4d27-819b-dbf3c9a94c42 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
df -Th / : /dev/nvme0n1p7 ext4   81G   12G   66G  16% /

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: V1.11(1.11) from Insyde Corp.
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this installed-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0002
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0002,0001,2001,2002,2003
Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager    HD(1,GPT,5e3bcfea-2416-4ecd-9ea8-f725ea96069f,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)57494e444f5753000100000088000000780000004200430044004f0042004a004500430054003d007b00390064006500610038003600320063002d0035006300640064002d0034006500370030002d0061006300630031002d006600330032006200330034003400640034003700390035007d00000034000100000010000000040000007fff0400
Boot0002* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,5e3bcfea-2416-4ecd-9ea8-f725ea96069f,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM    RC
Boot2003* EFI Network    RC


============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1    : is-GPT,    no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,     not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
nvme1n1    : is-GPT,    no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,     not-usb,    not-mmc, no-os,    no-wind,    34 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p7    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-efi ,    grub2,    grub-install,    grubenv-ok,    update-grub,    end-after-100GB
nvme0n1p1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,    no-docgrub,    nogrub,    nogrubinstall,    no-grubenv,    noupdategrub,    not-far
nvme0n1p6    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,    no-docgrub,    nogrub,    nogrubinstall,    no-grubenv,    noupdategrub,    end-after-100GB
nvme0n1p4    : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,    no-docgrub,    nogrub,    nogrubinstall,    no-grubenv,    noupdategrub,    end-after-100GB
nvme1n1p2    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,    no-docgrub,    nogrub,    nogrubinstall,    no-grubenv,    noupdategrub,    end-after-100GB
nvme0n1p5    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,    no-docgrub,    nogrub,    nogrubinstall,    no-grubenv,    noupdategrub,    end-after-100GB
nvme0n1p2    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,    no-docgrub,    nogrub,    nogrubinstall,    no-grubenv,    noupdategrub,    not-far

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p7    : isnotESP,    fstab-has-bad-efi,    no-nt,    no-winload,    no-recov-nor-hid,    no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4
nvme0n1p1    : is---ESP,    part-has-no-fstab,    no-nt,    no-winload,    no-recov-nor-hid,    no-bmgr,    notwinboot, vfat
nvme0n1p6    : isnotESP,    part-has-no-fstab,    no-nt,    no-winload,    recovery-or-hidden,    no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
nvme0n1p4    : isnotESP,    part-has-no-fstab,    no-nt,    haswinload,    no-recov-nor-hid,    no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
nvme1n1p2    : isnotESP,    part-has-no-fstab,    no-nt,    no-winload,    no-recov-nor-hid,    no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
nvme0n1p5    : isnotESP,    part-has-no-fstab,    no-nt,    no-winload,    no-recov-nor-hid,    no-bmgr,    notwinboot, 
nvme0n1p2    : isnotESP,    part-has-no-fstab,    no-nt,    no-winload,    no-recov-nor-hid,    no-bmgr,    notwinboot, 

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p7    : not--sepboot,    with-boot,    fstab-without-boot,    not-sep-usr,    with--usr,    fstab-without-usr,    std-grub.d,    nvme0n1
nvme0n1p1    : not--sepboot,    no---boot,    part-has-no-fstab,    not-sep-usr,    no---usr,    part-has-no-fstab,    no--grub.d,    nvme0n1
nvme0n1p6    : not--sepboot,    no---boot,    part-has-no-fstab,    not-sep-usr,    no---usr,    part-has-no-fstab,    no--grub.d,    nvme0n1
nvme0n1p4    : not--sepboot,    no---boot,    part-has-no-fstab,    not-sep-usr,    no---usr,    part-has-no-fstab,    no--grub.d,    nvme0n1
nvme1n1p2    : not--sepboot,    no---boot,    part-has-no-fstab,    not-sep-usr,    no---usr,    part-has-no-fstab,    no--grub.d,    nvme1n1
nvme0n1p5    : maybesepboot,    no---boot,    part-has-no-fstab,    not-sep-usr,    no---usr,    part-has-no-fstab,    no--grub.d,    nvme0n1
nvme0n1p2    : maybesepboot,    no---boot,    part-has-no-fstab,    not-sep-usr,    no---usr,    part-has-no-fstab,    no--grub.d,    nvme0n1

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk identifier: 56FCA379-04AA-4F06-9926-9ABF7EFAE766
             Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1      2048     534527    532480   260M EFI System
nvme0n1p2    534528     536575      2048     1M Microsoft LDM metadata
nvme0n1p3    536576     567295     30720    15M Microsoft reserved
nvme0n1p4    567296  441231359 440664064 210.1G Microsoft LDM data
nvme0n1p5 614967296  998117375 383150080 182.7G Microsoft LDM data
nvme0n1p6 998117376 1000214527   2097152     1G Windows recovery environment
nvme0n1p7 441231360  614967295 173735936  82.8G Linux filesystem
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk nvme1n1: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk identifier: 29BF0BCF-87D6-4180-9184-AFE8E23FDC65
         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
nvme1n1p1    34     32767     32734    16M Microsoft reserved
nvme1n1p2 32768 976771071 976738304 465.7G Microsoft basic data

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1:512GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:Micron_3400_MTFDKBA512TFH:;
1:1049kB:274MB:273MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp, no_automount;
2:274MB:275MB:1049kB::LDM metadata partition:;
3:275MB:290MB:15.7MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres, no_automount;
4:290MB:226GB:226GB:ntfs:LDM data partition:;
7:226GB:315GB:89.0GB:ext4::;
5:315GB:511GB:196GB::LDM data partition:;
6:511GB:512GB:1074MB:ntfs:Basic data partition:hidden, diag, no_automount;
nvme1n1:500GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:MSI M371 500GB:;
1:17.4kB:16.8MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
2:16.8MB:500GB:500GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL      PARTLABEL
nvme0n1                                                                                                   
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat     2E8F-8838                            5e3bcfea-2416-4ecd-9ea8-f725ea96069f ESP        EFI system partition
├─nvme0n1p2                                               e1a423db-d95b-11ee-b025-d2baab529ff6            LDM metadata partition
├─nvme0n1p3                                               cc8f19c7-ef0c-4de6-8fcb-2eaef580669f            Microsoft reserved partition
├─nvme0n1p4 ntfs     F28C90258C8FE289                     7dd71d20-ae2f-4fa2-b3c5-c55995ecaed2 Acer       LDM data partition
├─nvme0n1p5                                               e108073f-a5ea-11ef-b051-4c034ff0262b            LDM data partition
├─nvme0n1p6 ntfs     D006907D0690666E                     c85d59f3-67e0-4c2d-8b8d-d068b6a69c00 Recovery   Basic data partition
└─nvme0n1p7 ext4     539492ba-b8c5-4d27-819b-dbf3c9a94c42 af195034-1e93-41ba-9cd5-a6632cc7efb7            
nvme1n1                                                                                                   
├─nvme1n1p1                                               9127c03f-fd45-4b40-b7ba-d1112579df3d            Microsoft reserved partition
└─nvme1n1p2 ntfs     84FCBEB5FCBEA0BA                     3979951e-3067-4b0e-af6f-95016bc51956 New Volume Basic data partition

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                        Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p4            42G  80% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4
/dev/nvme0n1p6           289M  72% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p6
/dev/nvme0n1p7          65.2G  14% /
/dev/nvme1n1p2         143.1G  69% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme1n1p2
efivarfs                    0  99% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/nvme0n1p4         fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/nvme0n1p6         fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/nvme0n1p7         ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/nvme1n1p2         fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096

=================== nvme0n1p1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ===================

search.fs_uuid 539492ba-b8c5-4d27-819b-dbf3c9a94c42 root 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

=================== nvme0n1p7/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ====================

Ubuntu   539492ba-b8c5-4d27-819b-dbf3c9a94c42
Windows Boot Manager (on nvme1n1p1)   osprober-efi-2E8F-8838
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

======================== nvme0n1p7/etc/fstab (filtered) ========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p7 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/539492ba-b8c5-4d27-819b-dbf3c9a94c42 / ext4 defaults 0 1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/2E8F-8838 /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 1
/swap.img    none    swap    sw    0    0

==================== nvme0n1p7/etc/default/grub (filtered) =====================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`( . /etc/os-release; echo ${NAME:-Ubuntu} ) 2>/dev/null || echo Ubuntu`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

================= nvme0n1p7: Location of files loaded by Grub ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 218.639785767 = 234.762682368  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 254.145503998 = 272.886657024  boot/vmlinuz                                   2
 254.145503998 = 272.886657024  boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-41-generic                  2
 254.145503998 = 272.886657024  boot/vmlinuz.old                               2
 287.645503998 = 308.857008128  boot/initrd.img                                2
 287.645503998 = 308.857008128  boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-41-generic               2
 287.645503998 = 308.857008128  boot/initrd.img.old                            2

=================== nvme0n1p7: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ===================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18133 Apr  4  2024 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43202 Apr  4  2024 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14513 Apr  4  2024 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   786 Apr  4  2024 25_bli
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13120 Apr  4  2024 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1174 Apr  4  2024 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   722 Apr  5  2024 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Apr  4  2024 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Apr  4  2024 41_custom



Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub-efi of
nvme0n1p7,
using the following options:  nvme0n1p1/boot/efi
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the The OS now in use - Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS entry (nvme0n1p1/efi/****/grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message) file) !
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.
If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\****\grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message)

**UPDATE: I ran the list disk command in diskpart, i was unable to find my drive there Attached picture. The drive is visible in the UEFI menu. But as seen above, the drive is visible in list vol.
One other thing I noticed is that, as I was trying recovery from a UEFI stick, it said there were no backup files, so I was just searching folders, and I am able to see the BOOT, recovery and my Acer folders there.**

What happens when you select Windows directly in UEFI settings - Boot menu?

I will try to explain various tries at getting into windows,                                                         Case 1: Boot order priority Ubuntu:                                                                                           - trying windows from here just gets me blue screen with error "STOP_CODE: INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE"

Again, what happens when you try to boot Windows directly (UEFI), NOT from the Grub menu?

Case 2: Boot order priority windows:                                                                                    predator screen after restart, preparing automatic repair -> predator logo screen again, diagnosing your pc -> Blue screen with automatic repair couldn't repair your pc. I am given options for shutdown or advanced option here. I also get here; "log file: \?\GLOBALROOT\DEVICE........." ending in SrtTrail.txt.

So you need to boot Windows installation media and repair it from there. It has nothing to do with dual-boot or Grub - GRUB can't boot corrupt Windows - it was something that happened to Windows. What exactly is hard to impossible to ascertain now and not really relevant anyway.

So I get windows 11 on a usb, start the process and say repair? pardon me if that is wrong, i am a layman here. I just dont want to have to do a complete reinstall. Thank you for your help.

Yes, boot from it and choose the option to repair. There are a few different things it can do.

I will try that. Thank you once again.

I have tried windows recovery through USB. IT says windows wasn't able to repair.

A few other forums have said that I have somehow changed the disk type to old MDR. I have no idea how to go from here. What would I need to do to completely wipe out both ubuntu and windows, and then do a clean install of windows? I do not want some lingering issue from here popping up in the future.

No, you didn't change the partitioning type. Windows wouldn't still have a EFI entry if that were the case and Windows 11 doesn't support MBR anyway. And, no you don't need to start over but you can if you want. You just need to reinstall Windows. The problem is, from the start, you were biting more than you can chew and dual-booting is NOT something you can learn from a video.

I freely admit that I jumped in headfirst. I just got onto a project and I needed openFOAM for that. WSL2 kept throwing openGL errors at me for a day straight. So I just tried dual booting in a hurry.                                                                                                      So I plug in the recovery media, say install windows, clear out linux partitions? Please tell me if I am missing something, I have learnt not to jump in now.

You don't need to delete anything. Windows partitions can be reused; the others leave them alone.

Managing partitions is among the first things to learn when installing OSes. Even when only one blindly clicking "next" isn't always the best option.

I have added an update section in the question with pictures, I am unable to install windows again as the installation media does not show my drive. More of the issue is added in the original post under UPDATE. I would also like to remind that Ubuntu is running fine, i am typing and posting from here infact.

Are you sure you have two (physical) drives? You say so in the question but then partitioning one for the Ubuntu installation doesn't make sense. Typically one would just tell the second OS (Ubuntu) installer to install in the secondary blank drive and it would create all the necessary partitions in the blank drive - Currently only system partition is required - and also detect and use the ESP already there in the first drive.

Does UEFI has any special drive mode enabled - "RAID", Intel RST, etc. -? If so better to have AHCI for dual-booting. If this is TMI for you as I suspect it is then the best advice it to take to someone who knows.

Sorry for the late reply, I saw the message earlier but was occupied. My apologies for not updating the situation fully

I removed the second SSD to prevent it also from getting wiped/corrupted. It had no OS installations on it. As for RAID configurations, I saw that the VDM controller option was still turned off. So I have no idea why the drive is still not being detected.
